# Binding to selection of ViewModel

Tags: data-binding, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to bind my ListBox to a selection of my ViewModel, because I have multiple ListBoxes in a Pivot and I don't want to type out the entire Page for each property. To illustrate my issue, here's a small sample:

XAML:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="PropertyTemplate">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Label}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

    <controls:Pivot>
        <controls:PivotItem>
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding PropertySelectionOne}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PropertyTemplate}" />
        </controls:PivotItem>

        <controls:PivotItem>
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding PropertySelectionTwo}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PropertyTemplate}" />
        </controls:PivotItem>
    </controls:Pivot>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class SomeViewModel
{
    private Property _propOne;
    public Property PropOne
    {
        get { return _propOne; }
        set { _propOne = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("PropOne"); }
    }
    private Property _propTwo;
    public Property PropTwo
    {
        get { return _propTwo; }
        set { _propTwo = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("PropTwo"); }
    }
    private Property _propThree;
    public Property PropThree
    {
        get { return _propThree; }
        set { _propThree = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("PropThree"); }
    }
}
```

So basically I want to bind my ListBoxes to `PropertySelectionOne` and `PropertySelectionTwo`, which would contain references to a selection of the properties in my ViewModel. For instance, `PropertySelectionOne` could include `PropOne` and `PropTwo` and `PropertySelectionTwo` could include `PropTwo` and `PropThree`.

Is there a simple way to "group" these properties to a new property to bind against without changing the architecture of my application?

Thanks

Comment: Make an ObservableCollection<Property>. And add PropOne and PropTwo to it.  Then bind the ObservableCollection to the listbox's itemssource.

Comment: Evan, I actutually tried that, but it seems the collection has the correct number of items, but they're always null. The way I did it was just `ObservableCollection<Property> PropertyCollection;` and in the constructor `PropertyCollection = new ObservableCollection<Property> { PropOne, PropTwo }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've got different properties to be displayed from the same date type in different list boxes, then arguably you need to split your view model, but you say you don't want to change the architecture of your application, which is your choice.

So, what you need to do is to provide a different **ItemTemplate** for each ListBox that defines which properties and how you want to display in each ListBox. Then you can bind the **ItemsSource** for all of the list boxes to the same data source but they will present different properties according to the ItemTemplate.

Not sure how familiar you are with these concepts, but you know that **ItemsSource** needs to be a collection of your data instances (`SomeViewModel`?), right?

Comment: Thanks Derek, I already considered those two options, but the real gain I wanted from this is to have one generic ItemTemplate and bind to "collections" of properties in the same ViewModel.